# Searching for a decimal using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a search field and if you select 1 bedrooms, it should return all 1 bedrooms and 1.5 bedrooms. Search for 2 bedrooms, should return 2 bedrooms and 2.5 bedrooms. I am not sure how to search for the half bedrooms. Below is the relevant code. Thanks in advance.

listing_search_form.rb:

```
def bed_amounts
  String(bed_list).split(',')
    .reject(&:blank?)
end

def bed_list_scope
  if bed_amounts.empty?
    Listing.all
  elsif bed_amounts.include?('5+')
    Listing.where('bedrooms IN (?) OR bedrooms >= 5', bed_amounts - ['5+'])
  else
    Listing.where(bedrooms: bed_amounts)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you can, express the number of rooms as a string. Using decimal values here is going to be trouble due to rounding issues. A "one and a half bedroom" thing is an abstract concept anyway. It's not literally 1.500000 bedrooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a small transformation to `bed_amounts` in the beginning of 
`bed_list_scope` :

```
bed_amounts.push('2.5') if bed_amounts.include?('2')
bed_amounts.push('1.5') if bed_amounts.include?('1')
```

Not the best solution, but a start.

Full method:

```
def bed_list_scope
    bed_amounts.push('2.5') if bed_amounts.include?('2')
    bed_amounts.push('1.5') if bed_amounts.include?('1')
  if bed_amounts.empty?
    Listing.all
  elsif bed_amounts.include?(5)
    Listing.where('bedrooms IN (?) OR bedrooms > 5', bed_amounts)
  else
    Listing.where(bedrooms: bed_amounts)
  end
end
```

Comment: Could your clarify where exactly they should go as I am unclear. I am exploring all possible options. Thanks for your help!

Comment: While I didn't use the entire solution you provided, I took parts of it and figured out the rest. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your bed_amounts like this.
The to_i does the same as a .floor

```
def bed_amounts
  bed_list.to_s.split(',').map{|i| i.to_i}.uniq
end
```

Since I don't have your class I did a test like this

```
def bed_amounts bed_list
  bed_list.to_s.split(',').map{|i| i.to_i}.uniq
end
```

Which gives

```
bedrooms = [1,1.5,2,2.5,3.5,"5+",nil,""].join(",")
bed_amounts(bedrooms) #[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Your bed_list_scope could then be simplified like this

```
def bed_list_scope
  if bed_amounts.empty?
    Listing.all
  elsif bed_amounts.include?(5)
    Listing.where('bedrooms IN (?) OR bedrooms > 5', bed_amounts)
  else
    Listing.where(bedrooms: bed_amounts)
  end
end
```

Comment: the bedrooms = [] and bed_amounts(bedrooms) goes inside the bed_amounts method?

Comment: Any insight? Is it inside the method our out? When I put it outside I get an undefined_method bed_amounts error. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike, the 2 lines outside the method definitions are purely for testing and showing you the result (there would also have to be a parameter in bed_amounts), I publish nothing without testing, disregard them in your code, just replace the 2 methods. Edited the answer to make that more clear

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the clarification and help!